# VueJS: Setting a property if API response not received within x seconds

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My VueJS app uses axios for making requests to the backend. Let's say there is the following call:

`const response = await ApiService.getDocuments();`

The response might take some time (e.g. 5-10 seconds) as the server also performs background processing. Now I'd like to show a loading indicator but only if there is no response within e.g. 2 seconds. So the pseudo-code could look like this:

```js
this.showProgressIndidcator = false;
const response = await ApiService.getDocuments();

// this property shall be set if there is no response within 2 seconds
this.showProgressIndidcator = true;
```

How would I do what with VueJS? We also use lodash, which might provide something suitable?

Comment: I kinda don't understand this case, why you cannot show loading indicator right away after api is called? Why do you need to wait 2 seconds?

Comment: That's for UX reasons. If the API call returns immediately, the user would see a flickering screen with the loading indicator. I'd like to avoid this and only show the indicator if the operation takes a bit longer.

Comment: @ulou applies to things like *This page is taking longer than usual to load...*, is sometimes handy to delay loading states

Comment: I just don't feel that using `timeout` is a good way to handle this case. I was thinking more about something like this `this.$nextTick(() => this.showProgressIndidcator = true)`, but if timeout is enough for your case, thats ok, I guess.

Comment: @olou Ok, but how would you reset the property to `false` after this time span? Could you elaborate your approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a setTimeout, which runs after 2 seconds

```
// initial state
this.showProgressIndidcator = false;

// set state after 2 seconds
this.loadingTimer = setTimeout(() => this.showProgressIndidcator = true, 2000);

// call api
const response = await ApiService.getDocuments();

// clear timeout
clearTimeout(this.loadingTimer);

// clear state
this.showProgressIndidcator = false;
```